# Grouping objects and querying object groups in Java

Tags: java, memory, data-structures, structure

Let's say my program has a simple object, `Key`, that can be used as a key for a larger object. (this is out of the scope of the question) There may be hundreds our thousands of these keys flying around, so it is important to ensure that there is a minimal amount of duplication in different lists of these objects (so we don't clog the memory with useless objects).

[image: 6 Key objects]

The problem here is that these key objects may be grouped, and may be part of multiple groups at the same time. Let's split these 6 objects in 3 sample groups:

[image: 6 objects in 3 groups]

There is a single, concurrent list that keeps track of all of the groups, and there could be dozens of these groups created and removed constantly. But since this group system may be used for query operations such as, `Which groups is this Key inside of?`, we need some sort of indexation to quickly query from Object to Groups.

This is the system we currently have in place right now:

- A concurrent map (`ConcurrentMap<Key, Set<KeyGroup>>`, 'global map') that stores all of the groups, indexed using the keys themselves.
- Each `KeyGroup` contains a Set of `Key` (the contents of the group)
- When key *X* is added to a group *G*:

  1. Key *X* is added to the group's set of keys
  2. The group *G* is added to the global map with key *K* as the index
- To query in which groups a key is apart of, it is used against the global map as the index (`Set<KeyGroup> groups = globalMap.get(key)`)

---

The main issue with this system is the heavy duplication of `Key` objects:

- The global map has key objects to index the map (that's a `Set<Key>`)
- Each group contains it's own `Set<Key>`
- Since each group has it's own set, and each key has it's own set of groups, it increases the amount of `Keys` exponentially.

Obviously, we are looking into optimizing this whole process. Since we are using Java, are there libraries that can manage this system (which looks a little like a Venn diagram) **more efficiently**, and also avoiding the duplication of keys?

I also think that the built-in Java garbage collection doesn't clean this whole mess up when keys are no longer in use. Am I wrong? When I profiled the memory used by the program, the amount of Keys in the memory increases constantly, even though there are no 'new' groups being created / keys being added.

Comment: Your description is a little confusing. I think you're saying that you want to efficiently maintain two indexes: one that says which keys are contained in each group, and another that says which groups each key is a member of. Is that correct?

Comment: @JimMischel yes that is correct